# Speeding up a program in Processing that uses the Kinect

Tags: kinect, processing

I'm relatively new to programming. I put together a simulation of wall ball using Kinect and Processing:
https://github.com/nhsegal/kinect-3DWallBall

There's a noticeable lag between when a sound effect should be triggered and when it is actually played (~1 second). Is this lag due to poorly structured code or the inherent limitations of Processing? How can I reduce this lag? (And at the risk of getting downvotes for being vague, I'd like to solicit feedback to improve my code, even if the program can't be sped up much.)

Comment: It happens that I don't have my kinect with me so I can't fully test your sketch. Yet I stripped it from all the kinect specific code and ran it and I don't see any lag whatsoever (the effect plays instantly when the ball hits the ground or the walls). Thus it is either a matter of your computer, or something in the kinect code. As a test you should try to trigger the effect with a keypress so that you know which of the two like this: void keyPressed() { boing.play(); }

Comment: By the way I tested what I tested in Processing 2.0.1

Comment: I tried to reproduce what you did. I stripped out the kinect-specific code, controlling the paddle with mouseX and mouseY instead. I do notice a delay. I guess I have a slow computer. (I'm also using Processing 2.0.1, 32 bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from sonia to minim for sound improved things substantially. It's slow, but the boing sound is now synced with wall and paddle collisions.